# Applying a:hover:before condition for main menu on Wordpress Storefront theme

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, storefront

Greating everyone!

I'm trying to apply hover effects for main menu on a site run on Wordpress + WooCommece +  Storefront theme.
Hover effect is quite simple but includes **a:hover:before** condition.
Working code can be checked here https://codepen.io/0LEg_mao/pen/qBbRaPB

Same code applied to Storefront theme

```
    @media (min-width: 768px){ul.menu > li > a {
      position: relative;
     color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
     line-height: 24px;

        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px){ul.menu > li > a:before  {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        transition: transform .5s ease;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background: black;
        transform:  scaleX(0);
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px){ul.menu > li > a:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        transition: transform .5s ease;
        }
    }
@media (min-width: 768px){ul.menu > li > a:hover:before {
 transform:  scaleX(1);
    }
}
```

Result: I see at browser development tools (F12) that all CSS code is applied to main menu EXCEPT **a:hover:before** condition.
How to make **a:hover:before** condition working for main menu?

P.S. posting here link to my site might be more helpful in illustrating of what i'm trying to do but it migth be against rules

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. It isn't against the rules to post a link to your website as long as you have included the relevant code in your question in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This site is a Q&A site so questions need to be useful for other users who might have similar problems in the future.

Comment: @FluffyKitten thanks. Here is the link https://prettify.ru It is under development so there some mess in CSS styling... I'm trying to add hover effect to main menu on top

Comment: I don't see anything obvious that's causing the problem so it might be caused by one of your plugins or even the theme. Try disabling your plugins and see if it still happens. If the css works, then enable the plugins one by one to see which is causing the problem. If it's not a plugin then it could be something in the theme.

Comment: Finally I made it work. Just in case if someone will be using the same combination of theme and hover effect:
Add the following rule `@media (min-width: 768px){.main-navigation ul li a::before {
    display: block !important;
  }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I made it work. Just in case if someone will be using the same combination of theme and hover effect:
Add the following rule

```
@media (min-width: 768px){.main-navigation ul li a::before {     
display: block !important;   }}
```